# Spectral theorem - Why is $\mathbb{A}(v)=k^TA^Tc$?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

say $\mathbb{A}:V\rightarrow V$ is a linear and symmetric function with V an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

If $c=(c_1,...,c_n)$ is a orthonormal basis of $V$ (not spectral basis), $A$ the matrix of $\mathbb{A}$ regarding that basis (spectral theorem), $v=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\cdot c_i, k=(v_1,...,v_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then why is

$\mathbb{A}(v)=(Ak)^Tc=k^TA^Tc$?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with multiplying by a basis?  The left-hand side is a vector, but the right-hand is a vector times the ordered basis.

Comment: I understand your point and removed that thought of mine. I still don't get how one arrives at $k^TA^Tc$.

Comment: You should consult the source of this and tell us about it.  Where did you see it?  (Sometimes it is as simple as "oh, it was a typo in the book.")

Comment: Could you offer me a correct version of $\mathbb{A}(v)$? It might truly be a typo.